# Jquery not apply for loop call

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have this interface, when I clicked the checkbox, the input will open

[image: interface]

I use JQuery for this function and the problem is, only first row is able to open when checked the checkbox. Below are my code:

html:

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <tr>
          <th >Name</th>
          <th >Age</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach($peoples as $people)
          <tr>
            <td >
              <input type="checkbox" id="name" name="name" value=""/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
              {{$people->name}}
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="number" id="age" name="age" value="{{$people->age}}" disabled />
            </td>
          </tr>
        @endforeach

        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JQuery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#name').on('change', function () {
            $("#age").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
            $("#age").val('');
        });
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: This seems to repeat the same ID through a loop. This is the wrong way and you have to change the id every time the loop iterates over.

Comment: Once again - IDs must be unique - `$("#age")` will only reference the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are creating multiple HTML elements with the same ID. You can change those IDs to classes.

#### Dynamic approach

You can find the `.age` input that is in checkbox's parent `<tr>`:

```
@foreach($peoples as $people)
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="name" value=""/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        {{$people->name}}
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" class="age" value="{{$people->age}}" disabled />
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

And in the Javascript you find the `.age` input that belongs to the parent

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.name').on('change', function () {
        let input = $(this).closest('tr').find('input.age')
        input.prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
        input.val('');
    });
});
```

#### With row identifiers

You could also add an addition attribute to those inputs containing unique values of each one:

```
@foreach($peoples as $people)
    <tr>
    <td >
        <input type="checkbox" class="name" name="name_{{$people->id}}" person-id="{{$people->id}}"value=""/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        {{$people->name}}
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" class="age" name="age_{{$people->id}}" person-id="{{$people->id}}" value="{{$people->age}}" disabled />
    </td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

And then in the Javascript take one according to that attribute of the checkbox:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.name').on('change', function () {
        let id = $(this).attr('person-id')
        $('input.age[person-id="'+id+'"]').prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
        $('input.age[person-id="'+id+'"]').val('');
    });
});
```

Comment: Which is better in your opinion, using Dynamic approach or row identifiers approach ?
Is there any specific reason to use which approach is better ?

Comment: with the dynamic you have to be sure that there will always be the same structure (which i guess you have). With the IDs - you are just exposing IDs in the html code, but its nothing tragical, both are totally fine to use. Just personal preference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229543/discussion-between-wan-programmer-and-mike-b).